# How to Possible Expo React Native Firebase Phone Authentication in IOS

Tags: firebase, react-native

I Have Expo React Native in Firebaser Authentication Create and Also APK BUild Work Successfully BUt IOS in BUild Time:

> The Swift pod `FirebaseCoreInternal` depends upon `GoogleUtilities`, which does not define modules. To opt into those targets generating module maps (which is necessary to import them from Swift when building as static libraries), you may set `use_modular_headers!` globally in your Podfile, or specify `:modular_headers => true` for particular dependencies.

Problem Show,Please Given Solution for Expo React Native in Which file in Add to Modular Header. I DOnt Know please GIven Solutuion.

Comment: Check out the docs for [Firebase Cocoapods](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/installation-methods#cocoapods) which has good info a couple of links to details. This [release note](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios#version_900_-_may_3_2022) will be very helpful *Breaking change: Podfiles must include use_frameworks! or use_frameworks! :linkage => :static* - meaning the suggestion to “use_modular_headers!” does not work with FB 9+